# I want to create element in DB2 from input which we get from XML and JSON by validating it and need to store in DB2?

Tags: spring, web-services, db2

How can we validate input from XML and JSON, need to create that element in DB2?

Answer (score 0):

This page will help you with validating XML https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0050643.html

For JSON, as of Db2 11.1.3.3 you can use `SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON()` to validate that a string is valid JSON. To validate it conforms to some schema is less easy. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/r0070290.html

If you store your JSON data as BSON you know it will be valid JSON. Store your XML as XML datatype for validation and lots of other advantages.

`XMLTABLE()` is one way to extract elements from XML into other (non XML) Db2 columns. `JSON_TABLE()` can do similar for JSON.

For general info on Db2’s XML capability, google for “PureXML” as well as using information from the Knowledge Center manual.

(all above assumes you are using Db2 for Linux, Unix or Windows)